# The link between php connection identifier and Oracle v$session

Tags: php, oracle, sid

So i have a connection to Oracle database and it's identifier. What is the link between this connection and v$session view?
SID seems to be different than connection identifier.

[Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EV9vI.png)

Comment: Hi, please remember, we have not been looking over your shoulder all morning. We are more than willing to help but you have to give enough information for us to understand what your actual issue is

Comment: Please show what data you are talking about.  SID is the oracle internal session id.

Comment: $dbConn = oci_connect($dbu, $dbp, $db, $dbCharset);

So $dbConn is the connection handler.

v$session is a view where oracle keeps sessions informations.

How can i get information from v$session for this specific connection ($dbConn).

SELECT * FROM v$session WHERE .... i can't use the userid (username) because it may be used by more than 1 user... So there must be a unique identififier in session table.

RiggsFolly, thanks, but sometimes i think i asked the right question, but somehow i keep asking in the wrong way...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is this:

```
// Set the client information for Oracle tracing.
$clientInfo = uniqid('getInfoFromV$session_');
oci_set_client_info($connection, $clientInfo);
```

and then:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM v$session WHERE CLIENT_INFO = \''.$clientInfo.'\'';
```